# replace '0xNN' with a byte in a string in python

Tags: python

I have string say

```
string1 = '0x000x200x300x00'
```

I want result like

```
result = '\x00\x20...'
```

I want to replace every '0x' with '\x' . How to do it ?
I have tried replace function in python like as follows

```
y = x.replace('0x', '\x')
y = x.replace('0x', '\\x')
y = x.replace('0x', r'\x')
```

But no success :( .
Can anyone help in this issue ?

Comment: Note the difference in the *direction* of the slash. What is your expected output? Python will **not** treat the replaced values as string literal escape syntax..

Comment: You need to tell us what your expected output is; you did not define what *no success* **means**.

Comment: done editing of string

Comment: expected output for the string1 is '\x00\x20\x30\x00'

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add such important information. How many *characters* is your expected output? 4 or 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string1.replace("0x","\\x") use `\\`  to escape the `\`
```

`/` is also not the same as`\`.

```
string1 = '0x000x200x300x00'
print string1.replace("0x","\\x")

\x00\x20\x30\x00

In [19]: string1 = '0x000x200x300x00'

In [20]: print string1.replace("0x","\\x") # str
\x00\x20\x30\x00

In [21]: string1.replace("0x","\\x") # repr
Out[21]: '\\x00\\x20\\x30\\x00'
```

Comment: try `print string1.replace("0x","\\x")`

Comment: without print you are seeing the `repr` representation of the string which includes the escape `\\` char

Comment: ok. Thanks so much for the info. I will take care from next time

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are your trying to accomplish?

I am a bit wary to post this answer because it does not *directly* answer your question, but I *assume* you want to do some byte-mangling (wild guess) as you were not very explicit in your question.

If that's the case, then here's another "thing" you might want to do:

```
data = [int(_, 16) for _ in string1.split('0x')[1:]]
```

This will give you a list of `int`s representing the "byte"(?) values (of course depends what you want to do...)

The above code makes a couple of assumptions based on your example input:

- The input string will start with `0x`
- The input string does *not* include any non-escaped values. In other words, you always have a sequence of `0xnn` strings with *nothing* else in between!